# How to auto submit a checkbox

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

Here is HTML/JavaScript:

```
<form method = "post" style="display: inline;" name="thisform<?php echo $employee->id; ?>">
                     <input type="hidden" name="user" value="<?php echo $employee->id; ?>" />
                     <input type="hidden" name="auto" value="<?php echo $employee->stay_live; ?>" />
                    <h3><input type="checkbox" name="stay_live"  onclick="document.forms.thisform<?php echo $employee->id; ?>.submit();" <?php if ($employee->stay_live == '1') { echo "checked"; } ?> title="Click to Stay Live Every Day" />&nbsp;<?php echo $employee->name; ?> 
</form>
```

Here is `PHP`:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['stay_live'])) {
        $user=$_POST['user'];
        $auto=$_POST['auto'];


        if ($auto == 1) {
            $sql = "UPDATE users SET stay_live = 0 WHERE id = '{$user}';"; 
        }

        if ($auto != 1) {
            $sql = "UPDATE users SET stay_live = 1 WHERE id = '{$user}';";
        }

        mysqli_query($dbconnection, $sql);
    }
?>
```

If you see the `onclick` code in the form, it will auto-submit form and do PHP `POST`.  However, the `onclick` only works if the `checkbox` is NOT checked.  If it IS checked, the screen does refresh, as if it did thing, but the POST is never submitted.

So to summarize; everything works as expected when the box is not checked and it needs to be set.  But to UNSET it, the server function is never called.  Can anyone see why?

note:  this is test code, so please no comments on sql injection

Comment: This can be solve in jquery, can you make use of it ?

Comment: @Mollo I have do have some basic-intermediate knowledge of it.  How would you do it?

Comment: Give ma few minutes and I'll add my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkbox values are not sent when they are unchecked, so `$_POST["stay_live"]` is not set.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["user"])) // type="hidden" will be sent regardless of checkbox
{
    if (isset($_POST["stay_alive"])) echo "Checkbox checked";
    else echo "Checkbox not checked";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, see exactly what was wrong with my logic now... got it working with your help.

Answer (score 0):

Using Jquery I'd do the following: You need to make a file with the functions that you want to be executed. This file will receive via POST or GET

To your onclick attribute just add an if for your action variable, if(element checked) action = unchecked ---  else action = check

--Jquery function

```
function cBoxSubmit($employId, $action){ // call it in your onclick attribute.
   $.post("submitFunction.php",{action: $action, employId: $employId, ...},function(data){ // Parameters: URL file, variables which will receive, call back function
      if(data){
        // On Success or in your case if checked
        // add some code if needed
      }
      else{
          // If unchecked
          // add some code if needed
      }
   }
}
```

NOTE: echo == return in your php file ... This is how you return data to the call back function in your Jquery function

Comment: hey thanks, I'll see about implementing something like this perhaps

Comment: Yeah, it's really useful in some cases. I recomend you to read about POST calls in Jquery [link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)